# Bearer token error in a Java play framework using post request with WSResponse

Tags: java, playframework

In a post request made through F.Promise , I add a baerer token, but I get this error:

`{"ErrorCode":"401","ErrorDescription":"Authorization error (invalid_token): Invalid access token","ErrorName":"Unauthorized","ErrorStack":null}`

The problem seems to be caused by the fact that the first token retrieved (accessToken) is not passed correctly on the second post call to the server

```
        F.Promise<WSResponse> responsePromise = WS.url("https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Authorization/OAuth/Token")
                .setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(body.length()))
                .setHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + "Basic " + auth )
                .post(body).map(wsResponse -> {
                    JsonNode node = Json.parse(wsResponse.getBody());
                    if( wsResponse != null && wsResponse.getStatus() == 200){
                        JsonNode accessToken = node.path("access_token");
                        WS.url("https://XXXXXXXXXXXXX/1/Message")
                                .setHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
                                .setHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+accessToken)
                                .post("{\n" + \"Subject\":\"Appointment #1\",\n"
                                        "}").map(wsResponseSMS -> {
                                            return wsResponseSMS;
                        });

                }
```

How could I pass correctly the baerer token in the second function? Is the method correct to pass a variable to the next chained post request?

> .post(body).**map**(wsResponse ->

Comment: This look's good. There seem to be a typo in 1st query with basic Auth though: you put twice `"Basic"`

Comment: Is it 1st request or 2nd request that is failing? Please share the minimal code to reproduce.

Comment: The 2nd request failed, with the first request I retrieved the token, then I use the token retrieved to performer the 2nd

Comment: Whenever I have such problems, I take a step back and try to do the requests using an HTTP client like Insomnia or Postman, and try to get it to work there first. Are you able to make this work that way?

Comment: Also, have you tried to check if the token you get back is indeed valid, using something like the [jwt.io debugger](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io)?

Comment: If I try with postman works fine. I think that problem is the method map in post(body).map(wsResponse, seems that the accessToken, preoviusly obtained, is not passed correctly in the second chained request...

Comment: Did you print the accesstoken before making second ws call? is is getting printed properly?

Comment: Yes before is printed correctly